# Data integrity exception with hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

I created 300 records from backend with primary keys,  So now when these primary key's are generating through hibernate then data integrity exception shows.
Hilo algorithm is using to generate key's

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: (Hibernate operation: Could not execute JDBC batch update): data integrity violated by SQL 'insert into user_log (user_role_id, login_time, logout_time, appuser_id, logged_in_IP, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'; nested exception is org.postgresql.jdbc2.PBatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into user_log (user_role_id, login_time, logout_time, appuser_id, logged_in_IP, id) values ( was aborted. Call getNextException() to see the cause.
Batch entry 0 insert into user_log (user_role_id, login_time, logout_time, appuser_id, logged_in_IP, id) values ( was aborted. Call getNextException() to see the cause.
```

Comment: And what is the result of calling `getNextException()`? That should contain the _real_ error message from Postgres.

Comment: "So now when these primary key's are generating ..." why do you assume this? The exception is thrown when inserting the data in the database. (hi-lo is created before.) Isn't it a foreign key problem? You should provide more information, like java code of what you are actually doing.

Comment: Actually in my data base some tables had primary key as a int so when range of primary key increased out of range then keys auto set with minus number and around 300 records saved.So i changed these keys,i removed minus symbol from all tables and alter to all with bigint data_type.After that this exception shows randomly.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: when this error occur new row do not save  until server not re-started.